# Schedule a post expiration in Wordpress From publshed to draft for all posts older than 1 day

Tags: wordpress, post

I'm using Auto Post Scheduler to Publish one random post a day (from Draft).

My website concept is that there's only one blog post available at a time.

The one that has been published 24 hours ago, should go back to Draft again.

I couldn't find any plugin for that automation.

Can anyone please help me with the proper SQL command for that: moving from publish to draft any post that is older than 24 hours.

This should be a scheduled job, meaning it should automatically check published posts on a daily basis (once a day) and move it back to draft, if the post is older than 24h.

Isn't that to much for Wordpress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use Post Expirator plugin to do so

Comment: already tried and I can only set a fixed dates/times on the published posts, meaning I'd have to edit post everyday and set expiry date/time... I would like to avoid it...